# Filter a MySQL query depending on a column value BUT returning the rest of results that are sharing that specific value

Tags: php, mysql

let me explain what I mean on the subject. I have a query to db like this :

```
"SELECT * from partners WHERE idioma='$lang' OR idioma='EN' ORDER BY id_partner ASC";
```

This query will return several results, some of them may be repeated because my database has the translations and we have a multilingual webpage in which you can navigate in different languages. Let's say I'm navigating in German, what I need is to show all results that are in English (because I don't always have the translations for all the "partners") but, when I have a result in the specific language, filter that one and only shows the translated result .

I understand that the best option should be to already filter it from database. I can't figure out because everything I've tried so far still shows the EN results. Can you please help ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Please add sample data and expected outcome as text to the question.

Comment: Have you checked that the value of `$lang` matches that in the database for German entries?

Comment: I have this result that comes in DE:

array(2) { ["name"]=> string(28) "IHK- PROJEKTGESELLSCHAFT MBH" ["idioma"]=> string(2) "DE" }

And also in EN:

array(2) { ["name"]=> string(28) "IHK- PROJEKTGESELLSCHAFT MBH" ["idioma"]=> string(2) "EN" }

Apart of these, I got some other results that value IDIOMA is EN, and I also want those to be showed, but in the case I have 2 results for the same partner (IHK- PROJEKTGESELLSCHAFT MBH in this case) I only want the DE version in case I'm navigating in my page in German. Is it a bit clearer now?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting all the results correctly from database, the only thing that I need is to filter depending on the language I'm viewing the page, I'm getting $lang from the $_GET on the URL.

Comment: You shouldn't have said: _" I'm getting $lang from the $_GET on the URL."_.  This means your code is vulnerable to SQL-injection. This is a way to hack into your database. You should be using [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp).

Comment: This question can currently not be answered because crucial information is missing from the question. Please see P. Salmon's request. We need to know the other columns in the database table and what they do.

Comment: Hi KIKO, thanks for your help, I've solved this myself, finally, using the simplest and easiest way (not the best way, though), just making the select to exclude the ID of the result that I don't want to show: SELECT * from partners where idioma=$lang and ID != 89 (for example). Also, thanks for the advice about the SQL injection, I'll investigate it and try to solve this with the info you have provided.